# error: conflicting declaration of structure in multiple files

Tags: c++, c

```
//a.cpp has following code
#include "c.h"

extern "C" {
   extern const ABC abc_table[];
}

//b.h has

const ABC abc_table[] = {.....};

//c.h has
#include "b.h"
   typedef struct {.....} ABC;
```

this code compiles fine in visual studio

where as in Linux it gives following error

```
a.cpp:79:79: error: conflicting declaration of ‘const ABC abc_table []’ with ‘C’ linkage
 extern const ABC abc_table[];
                                                                              ^
In file included from c.h:4:0, from a.cpp:31:
b.h:147:1: note: previous declaration with ‘C++’ linkage
 abc_table [] =
```

how can I get rid of this error, and why is it different in windows and linux

Comment: `extern "C"` is not needed for variables, only functions. And why do you *define* a variable in a header file? You should declare it in a single header file, and then define it in a single *source* file.

Comment: And for your problem, keep both the declaration and definition *the same*. Do not specify different linkage (except the single `extern` in the declaration) between the two.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Strictly speaking.... Language linkage [does apply](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.link#4) to namespace scoped variable names. I imagine an implementation is free to do name mangling even at global scope, so this is needed to ensure proper linkage portably.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is ill-formed.

> **[dcl.link]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.link#5) If two declarations declare functions with the same name and
>   parameter-type-list to be members of the same namespace **or declare
>   objects with the same name to be members of the same namespace and the
>   declarations give the names different language linkages, the program
>   is ill-formed**; no diagnostic is required if the declarations appear
>   in different translation units. Except for functions with C++ linkage,
>   a function declaration without a linkage specification shall not
>   precede the first linkage specification for that function. A function
>   can be declared without a linkage specification after an explicit
>   linkage specification has been seen; the linkage explicitly specified
>   in the earlier declaration is not affected by such a function
>   declaration.

Wherever you include `a.h` and `b.h` both you get conflicting language linkage specification for the declarations of `abc_table`. Unlike with functions, variables have to match explicitly.

Either remove the linkage specification in `a.h`, or add it in `b.h`. Though then you have hit the problem of `b.h` defining an object name with internal linkage (on account of the `const`), so the symbol won't be found.

I'd dispense with the declaration in `b.h` all together. Object definitions in headers should be kept to a minimum, especially if one intends to interface with C code.